# What would cause a RedirectionException in a Windows Workflow Service?

Tags: .net, wcf, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

What exactly could be the root cause of the Workflow Service Host throwing the following type of RedirectionException:

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.RedirectionException: The requested resource has moved to the one of the following locations:
    http://blah.mydomain.com/MyWorkflowService.svc
    at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
    at System.ServiceModel.Activities.Dispatcher.ControlOperationInvoker.InvokeEnd(Object instance, Object[]& outputs, IAsyncResult result)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeEnd(MessageRpc& rpc)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage7(MessageRpc& rpc)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

The documentation for `RedirectionException` is generic in terms of WCF and I get what it's for, but I'm not sure what condition is triggering the Workflow Service Host itself to throw it and there doesn't seem to be any documentation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I have ever seen this happen but according to Reflector it is the result of an InstanceLockedException being thrown which happens when a WF instance cannot be locked. This could either be because another WorkflowServiceHost has locked and loaded it or because of some inconsistency in the instance store database.

Comment: Thanks, I was being lazy and didn't feel like disassembling/searching for it. Strange exception to throw in the face of those issues. In my particular case I'm running on a server farm and this is likely happening due to a longish running operation going on on ServerA with a secondary call to the same WF service coming in to ServerB. So in that case ServerB must be timing out on aquiring the lock and throwing the RedirectionException trying to tell the client to go to ServerA.

Comment: Yes that sounds reasonable. The only problem is that the client normally can't do so :-(

Comment: Hi @DrewMarsh, I am also facing the same issue in the server farm, i.e. my workflow service is hosted on 2 servers and one of the server is getting the same RedirectionException. So if this can be the cause as you have explained, how to check the same on the instance store (I am using SQL Server and persistence instance store) whether any server has lock on that. And if that is happening then what is the suggested fix? Thanks.